# Show that E(nx)=E(ny) => x=y

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For every natural number $n$

Show that : $E(nx)=E(ny) \implies x=y$

Such that $E(x)$ is the integer part of $x$

By definition :

$E(nx) \le nx<E(nx)+1$

$E(ny) \le ny<E(ny)+1$

So $-1 \le n(x-y)<1$

Here I'm stuck !

Edit 1:

Should I think about $x=E(x)+r$  $0<r<1$

Comment: What is the function $E$?

Comment: Its the integer part of x

Comment: If you got $n|x-y|\leq 1$ for all $n>0$, then $|x-y|\leq \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n>0$...

Comment: @Nicolas thank you :D it looks simple now :)

Comment: @user233658 You did all the work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has already been pointed out in the comments, from your last equation follows:

$$|x-y| \le \frac{1}{n} ~ \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \implies |x-y| = 0 \iff x=y$$

Because the absolute value is a [norm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) and then the last equality follows.

Comment: In this case n can't be 0 right ?

Comment: No, n has to be greater or equal than 1. If n is equal to 0 every pair x, y would satisfy the condition.